# Cloudformation nested stack outputs in yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

In my nested stacks I need to use output values and AWS::CloudFormation::Stack returns values as

Fn::GetAtt
Outputs.NestedStackOutputName

But yaml doesn't allow me to use

```
!GetAtt MyResourceName.Outputs.MyOutputName
```

as it tries to split them into 3 pieces instead of the 2 it requires.

I also tried using

```
Value: "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MyResourceName", "Outputs.MyOutputName" ]
```

but then I get

```
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 21, column 24:
        Value: "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MyResourceName", "Outputs.MyOutputName" ]
```

So how am I supposed to use this? Do I really have to switch to json for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to a [known bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/2332) in [`aws-cli`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli)'s custom [YAML-parsing code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/yamlhelper.py) that was added recently as part of the [`aws cloudformation deploy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) and [`aws cloudformation package`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) commands.

The issue was fixed in [version 1.11.37](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#11137) of `aws-cli`. To fix the issue, you can do either of the following:

- Upgrade `aws-cli` to version 1.11.37 or greater.
- Use `aws cloudformation [create|update]-stack` to create/update your stack instead of `aws cloudformation [package|deploy]`, if you're not making use of local artifacts.

Comment: Got reminded of this issue today and after some research i found that my aws cli was old and this issue was fixed.

Comment: @Jeppz ah, the additional context that you received this error from the aws cli (not from CloudFormation directly, as I had assumed) clarifies things! Updated my answer to describe the situation.

Answer (score 16):

It worked for me using these 2 stacks:

`root.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MyNestedStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/spg-test-bucket/cloudformation/nested.yml?versionId=HqlgDnuntMzkmK0398GPdJRUXMN_PMdn
  RootBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName:
          Fn::GetAtt: [MyNestedStack, Outputs.NestedBucket]
```

`nested.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  DataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite
Outputs:
  NestedBucket:
    Value:
      Ref: DataBucket
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. AWS documentation can really be lacking when it comes to syntax.